# Error trying to get Gitlab CI to run NPM and Gulp

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, gitlab, gitlab-ci

NPM installs correctly, but then I keep getting this error on my deploy.

```
npm info ok 
$ gulp
/bin/bash: line 48: gulp: command not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

My .gitlab-ci.yml looks like this

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
  - node_modules/

before_script:
  - npm install

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - gulp
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
```

My package.json includes the following

```
"scripts": {
  "install": "gulp",
  "test": "gulp test"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "gulp": "^3.9.1"
}
```

and I know my gulpfile.js is fine as it works great locally, running everything I need on either `npm install` or simply `gulp`. Really not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By running `npm install` you installing packages **locally**, it will be saved to project's `node_modules` folder and will not be available globally or as an alias(unless it's already installed globally). So in case if you want to use `gulp` alias you should install it globally: `npm install -g gulp` or you can run gulp from local `node_modules` folder with `./node_modules/.bin/gulp` command.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do either of the options you suggest, I end up with errors missing other dependencies that are defined in my gulpfile.js

Comment: I assume you need to install them as well, can you attach your `gulpfile` to the question?

Comment: I experimented with eliminating Gulp entirely and simply using NPM scripts as my build tool. Turned out to be a pretty easy solution and almost halves my dependencies, so I'm going with that. However, as your answer did solve my error, even though it wasn't the solution I went with, I'm accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

After I added -g flag it doesn't work for me anyway. 
To solve the issue I used "export" instruction.

```
before_script:
  - npm install -g grunt grunt-cli
  - export PATH=/usr/local/nodejs/node-v7.10.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin:$PATH
...
```